# In an ARM template, how do I assign a Service Bus role to an App Service?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I would like to define the access control (IAM) rules to a Service Bus Queue using an ARM template. I know how to do it for an Azure KeyVault so I defined the following template which creates a service bus namespace along with a queue and then assign the role of `Azure Service Bus Data Owner` to a function app:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionAppPrincipalId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
    "serviceBusName":                  "myServiceBus",
    "queueName":                       "creation-requests",
    "serviceBusUserRoleDefinitionId":  "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '090c5cfd-751d-490a-894a-3ce6f1109419')]", 
    "serviceBusRoleAssignmentName":    "[concat(variables('serviceBusName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', guid(uniqueString(variables('serviceBusName'))))]"
},
"resources": [ 
    {
        "name": "[variables('serviceBusName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
        "location": "canadaeast",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Basic"
        },
        "properties": {},
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                "name": "[variables('queueName')]",
                "type": "Queues",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', variables('serviceBusName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "lockDuration": "PT5M",
                    "defaultMessageTimeToLive": "P0Y0M1DT0H0M0S"
                }
            }]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/providers/roleAssignments",
        "name": "[variables('serviceBusRoleAssignmentName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
        "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('serviceBusUserRoleDefinitionId')]",
            "principalId": "[parameters('functionAppPrincipalId')]"
        }
    }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        
    }
}
```

Executing it results in the following error:

```
2020-12-23T17:57:52.3905460Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
2020-12-23T17:57:52.3941413Z ##[error]Details:
2020-12-23T17:57:52.3946096Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question**

In an ARM template, how do I assign a Service Bus role to an App Service?

Comment: Which scope do you want to create the role assignment?

Comment: @JoyWang The scope is at the subscription level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign an `Azure Service Bus Data Owner` to an App Service(per my understanding, you mean MSI here) at the subscription level, you could use the template below, it works for me.

**`template1.json`**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "roleDefinitionID": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the role definition ID used in the role assignment."
      }
    },
    "principalId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the principal ID assigned to the role."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "roleAssignmentName": "[guid(parameters('principalId'), parameters('roleDefinitionID'), subscription().id)]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[variables('roleAssignmentName')]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', parameters('roleDefinitionId'))]",
        "principalId": "[parameters('principalId')]",
        "scope": "[subscription().id]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**`parameters1.json`**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "roleDefinitionID": {
      "value": "090c5cfd-751d-490a-894a-3ce6f1109419"
    },
    "principalId": {
      "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Use PowerShell  `New-AzDeployment` to deploy the template at subscription scope.

```
New-AzDeployment -Location eastus -TemplateFile C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\template1.json -TemplateParameterFile C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\parameters1.json
```

[image]

**Check in the portal:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it only in 'service bus' scope and not in subscription+resource group? I want to give permission of 'Service bus sender' to my app service only inside a specific service bus and not inside all the service bus we have in the resource group / subscription.

Comment: change the `"scope": "[subscription().id]"` to `resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', variables('serviceBusName'))`

Comment: For anyone finding this: The scope needs to outside the properties, and use concat instead of resoureId if you want to specify all the way down on the resource level: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27254

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say, "The scope needs to outside the properties"? And how would you do role assignment in Bicep. Scope property is required.